# Using Javascript Replace function to remove € Symbol from String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but I'm trying to remove a € symbol from a String using `jQuery` as I'd like to be able to add the Values to a shopping cart.

Anyways, this is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/uuu8px6r/1/

I'm calling the javascript `replace` function on a variable which I presume shouldn't matter?

If anyone can't see my `fiddle` this is the `html`:

```
 <div id='shopping-cart'>
                <span><span id='s-qty'>0</span> Items in Cart</span>
                <span>€<span id='s-total'>0.00</span></span>
</div>
<p class="book-price">€7.99</p><div class='add-to-cart'>Add to Cart</div>
```

and my `jquery`:

var cartitems = 0;

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
        var bookprice = $(this).parent().find('.book-price').text();
        bookprice.replace('€', '');
        cartitems = parseFloat(cartitems + 1);                   
        price = bookprice;
        $('#s-qty').html(cartitems);
        $('#s-total').html(price)
});
```

The above code is giving me the following output:

€€7.99 (the euro symbol is never being removed).

Probably a trivial question, so apologies but I'm at a loss so would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure its `€` and not `&euro;`? BTW replace is *NOT* an in-place operation, as strings are immutable.

Comment: You are going to confirm pricing with the server before you submit the cart, yes?

Comment: @JamesHill yes definitely, but in this instance no as I'm not working with a DB it's just a demo version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` function is not an in-place operation in JavaScript, as strings are immutable. The following line replace the `€` symbol and the `&euro;` HTML special character:

```
bookprice = bookprice.replace('€', '').replace('&euro;', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bookprice = bookprice.replace('€', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 bookprice = bookprice.replace('€', '');
```

works correctly,
or

```
var bookprice = $(this).parent().find('.book-price').text().replace('€', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` does not mutate the string it is executed on, the new value is **returned** instead. You need to store it in a variable.

```
bookprice = bookprice.replace('€', '');
```

In your case:

```
price = bookprice.replace(/€|&euro/g, '')
```

This solution uses **regular expressions** to replace both `€` and html encoded `&euro` if present.

Answer (score 1):

Just Use

```
bookprice = bookprice.replace('€', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

just do it

```
price = bookprice.replace(/\s*\u20ac\s*/ig,'')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please try and include an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem, and why it might be better than the already accepted answer.

Comment: In case you're not aware, [OP means "Original Poster", the person who asked the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/349538).